# How to determine the size of collectionviewcell (xib)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is there a way to measure the width and height of a cell defined in xib from within "sizeforitemat" function or any other function of viewcontroller, once data is dynamically generated? The default layout of the collection view makes it very shabby as depicted in [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIj6b.png). Principally layout should have maximally two columns, and the rest of the empty spaces should be divided between cells within a row. So I want to loop over all the items, once it is filled with data to determine the maximum size of amongst cells to generate a layout according to its size. I'll highly appreciate the response.

viewcontroller.swift

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
    UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let myCell: String = "CollectionViewCell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:myCell, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: myCell)
        
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        150
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: myCell, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.lbl1.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.lbl2.text = "\(String(describing: cell.lbl2.text))\(indexPath.row)"
        print ("***", indexPath.item, cell.bounds.size, collectionView.frame.size)
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        // TODO: measure width and heigth of each cell to find number of columns
        
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }
}
```

collectionviewcell.swift

```
    import UIKit

    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

[viewcontroller's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxVbk.png)

[xib file's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKots.png)

[collection view cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFUwu.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIj6b.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask] (***please*** do not post images of code). First step should always be searching... head over to google (or your favorite engine) and search for `swift uicollectionview two columns`. You'll likely find exactly what you need.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I don't want to have fixed 2 columns, I would like to have no of columns as a variable quantity depending on width and height of a cell. So your search suggestion does't help me to achieve what I am aspiring

Comment: Your post stated *"layout should have maximally two columns"* ... so it's not clear. Can you add an image of what you ***want*** to achieve?

Comment: I appreciate your response. I was refering to https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIj6b.png. It has 4,3 and 2 columns. What I am aspiring to achieve is to first measure the width and height of all cells. Based on the largest cell size, divide the layout in columns. So In case of https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIj6b.png, It should be 2 since 2 cells of maximum size can fit within a screen. So it should be a 2 columns layout. Theoratically it could be 3, 4 or just even 1. If cells are too big. Is it bit clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the "widest" cell, you can:

- create an instance of your cell
- loop through your data, setting the label values
- get the width
- track the maximum width

Something like this:

```
    let theData: [String] = [
        "Short",
        "Longer",
        "A bit longer",
        "ABC",
        "This is the longest one",
        "Another medium",
        "Last one"
    ]
    
    
    let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    let c = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! CollectionViewCell

    var sz: CGSize = .zero
    var maxW: CGFloat = 0
    
    for i in 0..<theData.count {
    
        c.lbl1.text = "\(i)"
        c.lbl2.text = theData[i]
        
        sz = c.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 60.0),
                                       withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultLow,
                                       verticalFittingPriority: .required)

        maxW = max(maxW, sz.width)

        print("Row: \(i)", sz)
        
    }
    
    print("Max Width:", maxW)
```

Could give this in the debug output:

```
Row: 0 (50.0, 60.0)
Row: 1 (61.5, 60.0)
Row: 2 (95.5, 60.0)
Row: 3 (42.0, 60.0)
Row: 4 (179.5, 60.0)
Row: 5 (134.5, 60.0)
Row: 6 (73.5, 60.0)
Max Width: 179.5
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your response. This is exactly what I was looking for. I extend my gratitude. 
I have a subsidiary question related to the solution. I was wondering, what affect does it have on memory, since we are populating the data to determine the size? However the layout manager actually fills the data in "cellforitemat".

Comment: @jahnze - You could do some Profiling to find out exactly, but this should use very little memory. It creates only a **single** instance of the cell class, and then repeatedly changes the label text and asks the system for the resulting size. The collection view's memory management (re-using cells in `cellForItemAt`) is entirely separate.